# How to search through hashmap and print values lower than X?

Tags: java

I have a method which is supposed to search through a hashmap and print values lower than X (X being a user input).

What is the best way to go about doing this?

This is for Java. I am only allowed to use a hashmap, and nothing else.

edit:

I have tried to iterate through all values by getting the value at a keyset, but nothing prints.

```
public class price() {

HashMap<Integer, Integer> price = new HashMap<>(); //Hashmap.
price.put(1, 500);
price.put(2, 1000);
price.put(3, 1500); //etc

public void findLowerPrice(int x) {
        for (int y : price.values()) {
            if (x > y) {
                System.out.print(y + " Price: " + y);
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
   }
}
```

x is a user input, but lets say the user inputs 1000. 
The method should print the keys 1 & 2, along with their respective values of 500 and 1000.

Comment: What have you tried ? share some code, SO is not a self service coding website ;)

Comment: Edited with what I have tried.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. The code you are showing isn't ideal, but it should do the job. So: include your example data. As said [mcve]...

Comment: u can use ````price.values()```` instead of ````price.keySet()````. in java 8 u can use ````forEach```` and consumer

Comment: It's not printing anything because you're not calling `findLowerPrice`. If you are, then you should read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can see exactly what you're doing to get the result you claim to have, because the code otherwise looks like it works ok.

Comment: I'm trying to give working code but due to different IDE's/etc. I don't know what is considered minimal and reproducible.

Answer (score 2):

Using Java 8 Streams:

```
prices.entrySet()
  .stream()
  .filter(entry -> entry.getKey() < x)
  .forEach(entry -> System.out.printf("%d price: %d\n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
```

Comment: Java streams are not beginners material in my opinion.  Too much going on under the covers (including generics).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the lowest amongst the keys then, [`map.keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values--) can be used to get all the keys, simply iterate through them and find the lowest.

If you want to find the lowest amongst the values then, [`map.values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values--) can be used to get all the values and iterating through them and finding the lowest will solve your problem.

What you are doing seems to be good to me. May be there is no value that's lower than `x`.

you can avoid auto-boxing in your `for` loop by changing `int y` to `Integer y` (though it's not related here but it's a good thing to do) then it's better to use `Integer.compareTo()` instead of `>`

Another minor improvement is that you can use one single `System.out.println` instead of two.

HTH.

Comment: The values are predetermined so I already know what exists in the hashmap. It should be printing off multiple values and not just one. I need to be able to print off all the values which are lower than X, which it is not doing.

Comment: can you paste your complete code instead of the snippet. That will be helpful

Comment: Edited. Let me know if it is helpful.

Comment: I still see that the code is incomplete because the map is not initialized and I don't know the value of x

Comment: Edited again. The value of X is determined by user input, but I gave an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Price {

private static HashMap<Integer, Integer> priceMap = new HashMap<>();

Price() {
    priceMap.put(1, 500);
    priceMap.put(2, 1000);
    priceMap.put(3, 1500); //etc
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Price price = new Price();
    price.findLowerPrice(1000);
}

public void findLowerPrice(int x) {

    List<Integer> integerList = priceMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter((entry) -> entry.getValue() < x)
            .map((entry -> entry.getKey()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.print(integerList);
}
```

}